# URL Constraint for numeric IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I am trying to create some URL constraints for controllers to prevent null reference exceptions.

For example

/folder/edit/3 should be okay

/folder/edit/asdf shouldn't be okay

Instead of adding a Regex on every action method I want to use URL constraints for that.

The Problem I am facing right now is that the default route catches all requests, or if I am adding that constraint to the default route the standards request like http://host.tld/ aren't working anymore.

The constraint I am trying to add is

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RouteWithContraint",
    "folder/edit/{id}",
    new { controller="folder", action="edit", id="" },
    new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Does anyone has a hint for me on how to solve that problem? Or maybe someone knows a best practice on DRY for "IsANumber" checks for ids?

best regards,

Gordon

Answer (score 1):

How about to create custom ActionFilterAttribute for checking the type for some actions and/or controllers? Example of OnActionExecuting method of class inherited from ActionFilterAttribute:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      if (filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] == "edit" && !IsProperTypeofId()) 
         RedirectToRoute(filterContext, new { controller = "General", action = "Error", id = 401 });

      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Comment: An original approach +1 : )

But i think is overwhelming, what do you think?

Perhaps there is something we could do directly with routes..

Comment: Yep this is about the quick solution. Proper might be extending the routing functionality or so.

Answer (score 1):

The order that the routes are added matters. As a request comes in, the routes are checked one after the other until a match is found. Therefore you need to order your routes from most specific to least specific.

You may already have tried this, but if you add your custom route **before** the default route, do you have more luck?

Comment: Have you test this solution Randolpho? : O